# Carrierwave Setting Content-Type to Octet-Stream

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I'm creating a Rails 3 Application that uses Carrierwave & Amazon S3. The Problem that I'm running into is that when Carrierwave uploads images to Amazon it's setting the Content-Type to Application/Octet-Stream instead of it's actual content type.

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  storage :fog
  process :resize_to_limit => [100, 75]
  process :convert => 'png'

end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/issues/284#issuecomment-1925631:

> 1. Add `require 'carrierwave/processing/mime_types'` to an initializer or your uploader(s).
> 2. Add `include CarrierWave::MimeTypes` to your uploader.
> 3. Add `process :set_content_type` to your uploader(s).

Comment: I've tried this, but still get the same result of `"binary/octet-stream"`. I've even tried pull directly from the master branch on github.